# Android. Google Map. How to solve the problem with the light background when loading the map?

Tags: android, google-maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFsis.jpg)

The phone has a dark theme enabled. Before loading the tiles, the background is light. I can't fix it.

Comment: Even if you use https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com (Dark) it doesn't help

Comment: You can style your map based on the display mode selected, create a style from the link provided by @Gulamsounov above, export the XML, paste it in res->raw folder and set it to your map. You can even provide an on-map button to change modes just as a satellite view button.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar It doesn't help. Do not write comments just like that

Comment: The comment's purpose is to indicate how to go with the solution, it doesn't intend to be the solution.

Comment: There is already an entry for this issue in Google Public Issue Tracker. You can check it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/143487454